# Create a NumberFormat using currency

Tags: java, numbers, format, currency

really need help here.

I have my currency which is Currency.getInstance([some_currency]);
and now im trying to create a number format based on this currency in JAVA. is that possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: Java? If so please edit and add that tag

Comment: there is not locale for my desired money currency. of course i looked into that